# Restating Jenkins causes problems in Configuration slicing

Tags: jenkins

I am brand new user of Jenkins. I created jobs in Jenkins and set the global paths using configuration slicing. And then I cloned another jobs from previously created. So, the problem is when I restart the Jenkins all my jobs paths in the configuration slicing are changing with the other paths.

This is happening every time when I restart the Jenkins. So it is annoying me.

Can anyone help me out. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the Configuration Slicing plugin?

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Configuration+Slicing+Plugin

If brand new to Jenkins, I would stay away from complicated config setups that require plugins like the Config slicing mentioned above.

It should be possible to modify all the jobs at once with simple search & replace reg-ex on the job .xml files.  This allows you to modify all jobs at once without having to perform this operation inside the Jenkins UI.  Then you can enter the Jenkins admin and force a "read configuration from disk" to update the running Jenkins to match the changes you just made to the config on disk.

Hopefully that makes sense.  Also, if access to the file system for the Jenkins system is not possible, then this method of modifying all job variables in bulk won't work obviously.

I would also check to see if there are any plugins active that archive or track changes to job configs (job config history? SCM checkin configs?) that might be rolling back changes you make.